# найти примеры кода на C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

как открыть примеры начального уровня по C# на Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: Файл->Открыть->Проект/Решение. И почему именно Visual Studio 2013? На дворе 2017 год и студия есть соответствующая.

Answer (score 1):

Примеры проектов ты можешь найти [здесь](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio).
Как их открыть, ответили в комментариях. Что именно тебе нужно, из вопроса не ясно.